# cdbcriteria on join with two tables doesnt work

Tags: mysql, join, yii, criteria

am having two table tbl1(model1-pk-cid) and tbl2 (model2-fk-cid) cid of tbl1 is fk of tbl2 the traditinal sql works but with cdbcriteria it throws exception .am coding it in model1

my traditional query works in phpmyadmin

```
 select fp.*
 from tbl1 fp
  left join tbl2 fs  on fs.cid=fp.cid
   where ( fp.cid in (fs.cid) and fp.kat=3)
     group by fp.cid
```

but cdb criteria it throws exception (in model1)

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;


    $criteria->join = 'tbl2 as fs ON fs.cid=t.cid';
    $criteria->condition = 't.cid IN (fs.cid) and kat='.$id;
    $criteria->group = 't.cid';
```

exception thrown is

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `tbl1` `t` tbl2 as fs ON fs.cid=cid WHERE cid IN (fs.cid) and kat=3 GROUP BY cid)
```

am not understanding why is itdointhis

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
```

my query is

```
  (SELECT * FROM `tbl1` `t` tbl2 as fs ON fs.cid=cid WHERE cid IN (fs.cid) and kat=3 GROUP BY cid)
```

Please let me know am unable to figure out the issue

Comment: have you created model with relation?Add your model code

Comment: 'cid' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'model1', 'cid'), ........ relation in model2 of tbl2

Comment: add your controller and model code in question

Comment: What is the exact exception being thrown?

Comment: @topher exception thron SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `tbl1` `t` tbl2 as fs ON fs.cid=cid WHERE cid IN (fs.cid) and kat=3 GROUP BY cid)

Comment: @topher  exception thrown SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `tbl1` `t` tbl2 as fs ON fs.cid=cid WHERE cid IN (fs.cid) and kat=3 GROUP BY cid)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you missed JOIN keyword:

```
$criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN tbl2 as fs ON fs.cid=t.cid';
//                 ^^^^ ^^^^
```